# How to install electron.js on linux?

Tags: javascript, node.js, linux, npm, electron

I want to install electron.js on linux os. Need help to resolve the errors below:

**Command to install**

> sudo npm i electron

**Terminal output**

```
/usr/bin/electron -> /usr/lib/node_modules/electron/cli.js

electron@2.0.8 postinstall /usr/lib/node_modules/electron

node install.js

(node:13668) ExperimentalWarning: The fs.promises API is experimental
/usr/lib/node_modules/electron/install.js:54
  throw err
  ^

Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/lib/node_modules/electron/electron-tmp-download-13668-1536154444869'
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! electron@2.0.8 postinstall: `node install.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the electron@2.0.8 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/ebuilders/.npm/_logs/2018-09-05T13_34_04_997Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/lib/node_modules/electron/electron-tmp-download-13668-1536154444869'
This means the system executing the program (the instal) does not have permissions to create (mkdir) a directory on /usrlib/... Try to execute the install with sudo or setup NPM to use a different directory for installation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've run into this error before and installing with `sudo npm install -g electron --unsafe-perm=true --allow-root` worked every time.

I got the command from this comment: https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/10604#issuecomment-333368230

Comment: --unsafe should be an indication this might be dangerous. It has a very good reason this is an option and should preferably be avoided (--allow-root as well).

Comment: @SvenvandeScheur I guess you're right. This is just a quick and easy (albeit not the best) way to get it started

Answer (score 0):

If i remember correctly. I used to run into this error as well. What i did was give root access to the `install.js` script process and that seemed to work. Try something like `sudo npm i -D electron`the use of `sudo` with npm is not appropriate but it worked in my case

Answer (score 0):

This is a very typical problem in NPM environments. The root cause is that typically NPM want's to install stuff and write in a directory that the current user is not allowed to access.

There are 2 possbile solutions:

1. Change to a more privileged user, for instance using `sudo <command>` or `su`. This is a less ideal situation as its decreases security.
2. Reconfigure NPM/node to work within your local user account (better).

Please see the documentation on how to do this: https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions